# How can you get an attribute using Selenium 2 and PHPUnit?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to follow the URL of a hidden Log Out link. The HTML looks like this:

```
<li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item" href="http://www.ananda.org/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;_wpnonce=f633c2d0a4">Log Out</a>     </li>
```

Getting the element is straightforward:

```
$link = $this->byXPath( '//*[@id="wp-admin-bar-logout"]/a' );
```

Can I get attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can get attributes of elements, apparently, though I couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Here's the complete solution I used:

```
protected function doLogout() {

    $this->url('/wp-admin');
    $link = $this->byXPath( '//*[@id="wp-admin-bar-logout"]/a' );
    $this->url( $link->attribute('href') );

}
```